# How is this method called? (Pyglet)

Tags: python, pyglet

The following code is an alternative to the usual style (using decorators) pyglet makes use of.

Can anyone explain how the on_draw() method is called here?

```
import pyglet

class HelloWorldWindow(pyglet.window.Window): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(HelloWorldWindow, self).__init__() 
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world!') 

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear() 
        self.label.draw() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = HelloWorldWindow() 
    pyglet.app.run()
```

The code written using decorators can be found [here](http://vidyadev.com/wiki/index.php?title=Pyglet_Tutorial).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just dig through the [source](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet) to find the answer.

The [EventLoop](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet/app/base.py) class (you use it by `pyglet.app.run()`) dispatches the `on_draw` event regulary.

From the source:

> Calling `run` begins the application event loop, which processes
>   operating system events, calls `pyglet.clock.tick` to call scheduled
>   functions and calls `pyglet.window.Window.on_draw` and
>   `pyglet.window.Window.flip` to update window contents.

The [Window](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet/window/__init__.py) class subscripes to this event:

```
BaseWindow.register_event_type('on_draw')
```

So by subclassing `Window`, you ensure your `on_draw` method gets called.

Look at the [programming guide](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/setting_event_handlers.html) for an example of how the event system of pyglet works.